# Is there something like Restrictions.eq(true, false) in Criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, criteria-api

I need a generic `Criterion` which forces the result to zero matches.

Something like `Restrictions.eq(true, false)` ?

Comment: What kind if criteria are you talking about? What technology? Language? Platform?

Comment: Added the java tag for upcoming readers, thank you Stefan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use in NHibernate (C#):

```
Restrictions.Sql("(1=0)");
```

or in Hibernate (Java):

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(1=0)");
```

:-)

Comment: `Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(1=0)")` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

In Hibernate you might use `sqlRestriction`:

http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

I used below code in hibernate and it worked for me:

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1=0")
```